# the html text input that i create using jquery and add more button is not sending any value in post method

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, input, file-io

i have a simple question hope you can help me .
I have a form and there are some in put fields that i add by addmore button .. but when i add file and descriptions it s not sending values..here is my form

```
                  <div class="row clone">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label class="mr-2 ml-2">Görsel</label>
                      <div class="input-group control-group ml-2">
                        <input type="file" name="image_name[]" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label class="mr-2 ml-2">Meta Açıklama</label>
                      <div class=" input-group mr-2 ">
                        <input type="text" name="image_description[]" class="form-control"> 
                        <span id="addFile" class="btn btn-success ml-2 mr-2">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle "></i></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden row" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="row removeable col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-6 ">
                        <label class="mr-2 ml-2">Görsel</label>
                        <div class="input-group ml-2">
                          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_name[]">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="mr-2 ml-2">Meta Açıklama</label>
                        <div class="input-group control-group ml-2 ">
                          <input type="text" name="image_description[]" class="form-control" >
                          <span class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mr-1 removeBtn">
                          <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

and i create this extra file input by addmore button with jquery below

```
  $("#addFile").click(function() {
  var lsthmtl = $(".hidden").html();
  $(".clone").append(lsthmtl);

});
$("body").on("click", ".removeBtn", function() {
  $(this).parents(".removeable").remove();

});
```

but when i checked the request , only first file and description input values are coming..the inputs that i created by addmore button are nt sending values.Is there anyone have any idea ??

Comment: provide a working snippet of what you have

Comment: this is working snippet.. the inputs that i created by button doesnt send value.. i tried to add whole off the form and controller but  i  couldnt arrange the text editor